# compare 2 csv files and output only difference into variable

Tags: csv, file-comparison, comm

1.csv:

```
rundeck-read-only-iam-permissions,IAMReadOnlyAccess
citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning",AmazonEC2FullAccess
```

2.csv:

```
 citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning",AmazonEC2FullAAA
citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning",AmazonS3FullAccess
rundeck-read-only-iam-permissions,IAMReadOnlyAccess
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq,qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
```

Note that order is not the same

I want to compare difference in file 2.csv against file 1.csv (and order lines in 2.csv to match order in 1.csv

If there is no change print: No changes
if line in file 1.csv is changed print Line that has changed+ line-content,
if line in file 1.csv is missing print "Line that was removed + line-content,
if line in file 1.csv is added print "Line was added" + line-content,
so far, i have this, it prints desired output but is it possible to detect what was added/removed

```
      comm -1 -3 <(sort 1.csv) <(sort 2.csv)
citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning",AmazonEC2FullAAA
citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning",AmazonS3FullAccess
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq,qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `diff`:  `if diff <(sort 1.csv) <(sort 2.csv); then echo "No changes"; fi`.  If there are differences, they will be shown in a standard `diff` format.  If there are no differences, `diff` has no output and returns zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diff` is probably the tool you want.  Here are three example files:

```
$ paste foo bar baz
aaa aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaz
aaa aaa aaa
$ if diff <(sort foo) <(sort bar); then echo "No differences"; fi
No differences
$ if diff <(sort foo) <(sort baz); then echo "No differences"; fi
3c3
< aaa
---
> aaz
```